# mkdosfs hangs forever, even when using timeout

Tags: usb, usb-drive, mkfs

I'm testing massive amounts of USB flash drives using a custom bash script that's based on [*f3*](http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3).

Before I perform `f3write` and `f3read` I format the drives, as my experience is some of the drives come from the factory not formatted properly - and hence cannot be used (or tested) in that such state.

When I perform the testing, some of the bad drives hang the `mkdosfs -I -F32` process forver.

I've tried using `timeout` with `SIGKILL` to forcefully terminate the mkdosfs process after a few minutes if it doesn't finish, but that doesn't work.

I've read that processes which execute kernel calls might go into uninterruptible sleep marked with a letter '*D*' in `top` or `htop`.

That seems to be the case - the only way to terminate the processes I have found so far is to physically disconnect the USB flash drive that is being worked on.

Right now these bad drives just never finish formatting. Here's a screenshot from `htop`:

[image]

I wonder what can I do to be able to stop the process - or at least detect that it has hung so I can notify the user. Maybe there's some software way to reset the USB port?